# List appends and calling a class within itself

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I have code that looks like this:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, my_list=[]):
        self.my_list = my_list
    def add_stuff(self, nums):
        self.my_list.extend(nums)


x = Test()
x.add_stuff([1,2,3])
x.add_stuff([5,4,2,1])
```

Doing the append to the list in the case of the second x results in appending [1,2,3],[5,4,2,1] into the self.answers list. If I want a result where `x.my_list=[1,2,3]` and `x.my_list=[5,4,2,1]`, what needs to be done? I still want to return/access the object and its data outside of the class but only contain the values that got passed in upon that method call.

Comment: Your code has *numerous problems*. I picked one (using a default argument value that is mutable). Use `list.extend()` to extend a list with multiple values.

Comment: Your `addStuff()` method should not return a new instance of `Test()`. Use `x = Test()` then on a separate line use `x.addStuff()`.